# Production build of Angular 7 with React component rendered within

Tags: reactjs, angular, bundle, wrapper

I'm migrating an existing Angular app to React piece by piece.  Looked at a number of options including single-spa and nx, but they're not feasible because the existing app is a horrible pile of script-injected madness.  I've opted for the semi-manual option as shown by Zacky Pickholz:

https://medium.com/@zacky_14189/embedding-react-components-in-angular-the-easy-way-60f796b68aef

The project is successfully rendering a React component inside the Angular 7 app (yay!). Dev build works fine, however the production build throws up at the tsx wrapper.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/my-wrapper-rct/my-wrapper-rct.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (21:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   const containerElementName = 'myWrapperRct';
|
|   @Component({
|     selector: 'my-wrapper-rct',
|     template: `<span #${containerElementName}></span>`,
```

The wrapper looks like the example from Zacky's repo:
https://github.com/zackypick/react-in-angular

It looks like the production transpiler is ignoring the tsx wrapper, so when the JS encounters `@Component` it has no idea what to do with it. The weird thing is that the bundles seem to transpile and generate prior to this error. Hoping someone has some insight into the production build error.

Wrapper code:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnDestroy,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';
import { MyReactComponent } from 'src/components/my-react-component/MyReactComponent';
import * as React from 'react';

import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const containerElementName = 'myReactComponentContainer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `<span #${containerElementName}></span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./MyReactComponent.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyComponentWrapperComponent implements OnChanges, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(containerElementName, {static: false}) containerRef: ElementRef;

  @Input() public counter = 10;
  @Output() public componentClick = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor() {
    this.handleDivClicked = this.handleDivClicked.bind(this);
  }

  public handleDivClicked() {
    if (this.componentClick) {
      this.componentClick.emit();
      this.render();
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.render();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.render();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.containerRef.nativeElement);
  }

  private render() {
    const {counter} = this;

    ReactDOM.render(<div className={'i-am-classy'}>
      <MyReactComponent counter={counter} onClick={this.handleDivClicked}/>
    </div>, this.containerRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to understand why someone downvotes a legitimate question. Do they love Angular so much that they can't fathom using a better technology? :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Searched the ends of the earth and didn't find anyone facing the exact same error. This reported issue clued me in on some paths to take:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9244

After some experimentation, I needed to set `aot` and `buildOptimizer` to false. They're unable to deal with this situation.

The build size difference was minimal: 8.3MB vs 8.4MB.  Since the goal is to jettison Angular ASAP, I can live with this small increase.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer. I am having this exact issue

Comment: @bendozy I need more information on the issue you're facing. I set the above flags to false in `angular.json`

Comment: This is not an answer, I'd recommend not using tsx altogether since it's not supported :/ and just use ts or precompile. The Angular cli doesn't recognize tsx files and does not import React properly thus you will get an undefined React variable on prod output.

Comment: tsx works fine using the approach in the OP. It's clear you're convinced it doesn't, but it's been shown to work and it works well.

Answer (score -1):

React is not autoimported after compilation of tsx and thus React does not get imported on production builds (aot or buildoptimizer). Thus, it is recommended to add the following to the root of the module where you use React components. In my case it was a lazy loaded module via route.

```
import React from 'react'; 
window.React = React;
```

This will add React to your global namespace and make it accessible in your component.

Comment: Adding a global variable isn't good practice, especially for a transpiled bundle. It may work in your case, but could lead to problems in others. The correct answer, contrary to your comment above, is to fix the transpilation and bundling process.